# Local beers to try at airports (major airports only)

Tags: breweries, local

I fly a lot, and like to seek out new beers while waiting or between connecting flights. Frequent flyers: let's help each other out and compile (community wiki-style) a list of establishments in major airports that serve local beers.

For definition's sake, though arbitrary, let's say a "major airport" is one which

- serves more than [5,000,000+ passengers per year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_in_the_United_States) ("enplanements"),
- or serves the *most* passengers per year in its country.

So, outside of the U.S., check the airport's Wikipedia page for the stats—for example [Berlin's Schönefeld Airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nefeld_International_Airport), with 7,000,000+ enplanements in 2010. Also eligible are airports like [Luxembourg's main airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxembourg-Findel_International_Airport), serving less than 5,000,000 passengers per year, but the most in its country. If this definition seems to rule out some rather important airports, we can modify the rules.

This list would probably help me with "tiebreaking" when I can't decide what flights I'd rather take. It would also give me a reason to enjoy longer-than-desired connections :-)

---

<sup>This is a question asked among the series of regional-but-potentially-useful-if-specific-enough questions. See</sup>

- <sup>[Asking brand-specific / regional questions "responsibly"](https://alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67/asking-brand-specific-regional-questions-responsibly)</sup>
- <sup>[What kinds of questions will keep Beer.SE active? (Relax the culture against brands and regional questions.)](https://alcohol.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55/what-kinds-of-questions-will-keep-beer-se-active-relax-the-culture-against-bra)</sup>

Comment: To be honnest, this question is isn't suited for SE...

Comment: @LucasKauffman I agree; maybe good for beer advocate, but not here.

Comment: @LucasKauffman (and @audiFanatic) - Yeah, I tend to agree. I was trying to push the boundaries (see linked questions in the fine-print) to get more activity flowing on the site. I'm okay with the community voting to close it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a **community wiki**. Please be respectful while editing others' contributions.

Let's keep the list alphabetical [by IATA code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_by_IATA_code:_S).

### ATL — Hartsfield–Jackson Atlanta Int'l Airport

- Concourse B. *SweetWater Draft House & Grill*.

### BOS - Logan Int'l Airport

- Terminal A / Gate A22. *Harpoon Tap Room*. (Highly rated!)

  [image]

### CLE - Cleveland Hopkins Airport

- Main Terminal Great Lakes Brewery
  https://www.greatlakesbrewing.com/home
  Full selection of beers on tap.

  The Edmund Fitzgerald Porter is delicious and year-round, but the Spring 2014 seasonal is most likely the Chill Wave Double IPA, which is one of their best.
  Sometimes, they have brewery-exclusive kegs, which are always very good!

  [image]

### JFK - John F. Kennedy Int'l Airport

- Terminal 2 / Gate 67. (That's most popularly the Domestic US Delta terminal.) *BRKLYN Beer Garden*. As of 2014, they've got 6 Brooklyn / Bronx beers on draught, and a few from Long Island and upstate.

  [image]

  <sup>Source: acheong87</sup>

### LHR - London Heathrow

- Terminal 5 / near gate A7. *The Crown Rivers* always has some real ale on tap, from a hand pump.

### MSP - Minneapolis / St. Paul Int'l Airport

- Terminal 1 / Concourse G near gate 17. *Taste of Mill City Tavern* serving Surly Bender, Summit IPA, Fulton Sweet Child of Vine and Shell's Pilsner on tap.

### ORD - Chicago O'Hare Int'l Airport

- Terminal 3 / Gate L8. *Goose Island Beer Company*.

  [image]

### SAN - San Diego Int'l Airport

- Terminal 2 / Gate 23. (Terminal 2 is the more popular of SAN's two terminals, *by far*.) [*Stone Brewing World Bistro & Gardens*](http://blog.stonebrew.com/index.php/stoneairport/) features 12 taps—10 Stone brews, 2 rotations from other craft brewing companies—and many bottled selections.

  [image]

  <sup>Source: http://blog.stonebrew.com/index.php/stoneairport/</sup>

### TPA - Tampa Int'l Airport

- Airside C Terminal. *Cigar City Brewing*. Advertised on website as "nation's only airport brewery" with airport exclusive beers and Tampa-style cuban food.

  [image]

  <sup>Source: http://cigarcitybrewing.com/cigar-city-brewing-airport-location/?age-verified=90aad2c053</sup>

Comment: If this list grows to any substantial length the photos will make the page very long (more hassle to scroll through).  Are they needed?  Could they just be linked instead?

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Hm, good point. Let's (again, arbitrarily) agree for now that we'll remove all photos (or replace them with links) once we reach, er... 10?

Comment: I'd say keep the photos. I wouldn't bother clicking a link and without a photo I wouldn't even bother reading the text. A pictures says a thousand words!